# Electron: Invalid dependencies have been reported by plugins or loaders for this module

Tags: electron, electron-forge

Invalid dependencies have been reported by plugins or loaders for this module. All reported dependencies need to be absolute paths.

I am using electron-forge to create electron app but when I try to import ipcRenderer or even ipcMain it gives me the error of "Invalid dependencies have been reported by plugins or loaders for this module. All reported dependencies need to be absolute paths."